# Php code error in wordpress if else statements

Tags: php, loop

I have created an if statement inside the "else" of an if/else statement.However the code below the function does not run.When i remove the function the code below the function runs.Could you please help me out.

This code causes the problem:

```
    <?php $googleplay= get_option('director_googleplay');?>
    <?php if($googleplay): ?>
        <a href="<?php print $googleplay; ?>">
            <img src="<?=IMAGES?>/googleplay.png" class=" img-responsive  top-buffer-5"  alt="Image"/>
        </>
    <?php endif;?>
```

The php:

```
  <?php  $category_id = get_cat_ID('Category Name'); ?>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php if ( in_category("1") ) { ?>
   <div class="section">
  </div>

 <?php } elseif ( in_category("2") ) { ?>
   <div class="section">
 </div>

  <?php } else { ?>
  <div class="section">
  <?php $googleplay= get_option('director_googleplay');?>
    <?php if($googleplay): ?><a href="<?php print
     $googleplay; ?>"><img src="<?=IMAGES?>/googleplay.png" class=" img-responsive  top-buffer-5"  alt="Image"/></><?php endif;;?> 
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
   <?php endwhile;else: ?>
  <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
   <?php endif; ?>

   <div class="section">
   <?php $facebook= get_option('director_facebook');<?php if($facebook): ?><a href="<?php print
  $facebook; ?>"><img src="<?=IMAGES?>/Facebook.png" class=" img-responsive pull-left"alt="Image"/></><?php endif; ?>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple syntax errors in your code, see comments in below code:

**Code:**

```
    <?php $googleplay = get_option('director_googleplay'); ?>
    <?php if( $googleplay ) : ?>
        // use echo not print
        <a href="<?php echo $googleplay; ?>">
            // rework your src/IMAGES statement
            // is this a constant/variable?
            <img src="<?php echo IMAGES; ?>/googleplay.png" class=" img-responsive  top-buffer-5"  alt="Image"/>
        // you haven't closed your <a> tag
        </a>
    // remove double semicolon
    <?php endif; ?>
```

For future reference, make use of [Debugging in Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to analyze/check your code.

Comment: It Doesn't work

Comment: What doesn't work? Have you debugged you code? Did you make sure that the src of your img tag is correct? Have you check that your option respectively the $googleplay variable and the if statement is actually giving you the result you expect? You have to check on those things yourself, right? @user3274745

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work.Now, No errors are found when debugging it. Is there a way to add "else else if" to the function so that the loop can be extended and i can get the lower part into the function?

Comment: Ok i got it working by adding an extra else statement to it. Though it doesn't make sense.Must be some wordpress error

Comment: @user3274745 don't blame your tool if you can't get your code right.